# Scheduling an ETL file in Tivoli

Tags: scheduled-tasks, etl, job-scheduling, tivoli-work-scheduler

I want to **schedule an etl job file (.vbs) in Tivoli**. I am able to schedule it in Windows task Scheduler. As I have never tried my hands on Tivoli. Can anyone help me on this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To start a .vbs from command line, you should run `cscript <script>.vbs`.

A TWS job running `cscript <script>.vbs` should address your scenario.

If your ETL is based on MS-SQL you can also look at Database jobs running on dynamic agents.